# HTML/CSS-Removing the gray edges around a pdf object

Tags: html, css, object, pdf

I am trying to put a pdf object on my web page. The pdf loads fine, but it creates a gray area around the document. I know that the gray area is part of the pdf document and it is just part of the object, but I am trying to find out how to get rid of it. I have adjusted margins and padding. I have adjusted height and width to try and get it to go away. I have tried passing a zoom option to the pdf when it opens and nothing worked.

I want the document to load without creating any sort of edges or borders on the page. Any help would be appreciated. The markup that applies to it is below. I'm pretty sure it won't help much but you never know.

```
<article class="main_content">

    <object id="resume_object" type="application/pdf"  data="images/AlexsResume30Jan15.pdf">Alex's Resume</object>

</article>

article.main_content{
    margin-top:70px;
}

#resume_object{
    height:1190px;
    width: 910px;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right:20%;
    padding:-20px;
    background-color:white;

 }
```

Comment: Is cropping the the PDF server-side an option?

Comment: Maybe but I don't think it's the problem. The gray borders aren't part of the original file. They only show up when they are on the html document

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It seems everyone that's asked this question on here, or anywhere, never gets an answer.